# MySQL - PHP order by the Inner Joining table id rather than the Selected table ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following query which i want to order by the UserView ID descending, seems like pretty basic question but i cant figure out how to do it, i want keep selecting the User.* as it now, but order by the UsersView table primary key desc, Any ideas ?

```
 $phql = " SELECT *
                      FROM User
                      WHERE user_id IN
                      ( SELECT user_to
                        FROM UsersView
                        WHERE user_from=:user_to: )
                      AND gender!=:gender:
                      AND user_id NOT IN (".implode(",",$this->user->getBlocked()).")
                      ORDER BY last_visit DESC
                 /* order by should be usersview.id DESC */ 
                      ";
```

Any luck with this ?

Comment: `ORDER BY last_visit DESC, usersview.id DESC`

Comment: sql fiddle would be awesome

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your data model, you can do an additional join back to UsersView so that you can use it's id column in your ORDER BY clause.

```
 $phql = " SELECT *
                  FROM User
        JOIN UsersView on User.user_id = UsersView.user_to
                  WHERE user_id IN
                  ( SELECT user_to
                    FROM UsersView
                    WHERE user_from=:user_to: )
                  AND gender!=:gender:
                  AND user_id NOT IN (".implode(",",$this->user->getBlocked()).")
                  ORDER BY UsersView.id DESC";
```

You may also be able to avoid using the nested select to do the filter and use the joined table to do the filter instead:

```
 $phql = " SELECT *
                  FROM User
        JOIN UsersView on User.user_id = UsersView.user_to
                  WHERE user_from=:user_to:
                  AND gender!=:gender:
                  AND user_id NOT IN (".implode(",",$this->user->getBlocked()).")
                  ORDER BY UsersView.id DESC";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't really have enough information to answer the question exactly which is why someone asked for your table structures.

I believe I know what you are asking so I am going to 'guess' at your table structure.  Here is the structure, data, and solution that I think will put you on the right path. I also removed the PHP since it isn't relevant to your question.

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (user_id int, gender varchar(1));
CREATE TABLE UsersView (user_to int, user_from int, last_visit datetime);

INSERT INTO `User` VALUES
(1, 'M'),(2, 'F'),(3, 'M'),(4, 'F'),(5, 'F');

INSERT INTO UsersView VALUES
(2, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(3, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(4, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(5, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(1, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(3, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(4, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(5, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(1, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(2, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(4, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(5, 3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(1, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(2, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(3, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
(5, 4, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);                      


SELECT u.user_id, max(v.last_visit)
FROM User u
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersView v ON u.user_id = v.user_to
WHERE u.user_id IN (
    SELECT user_to
    FROM UsersView
    WHERE user_from=1
)
AND u.gender != 'M'
AND u.user_id NOT IN (1)
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY max(v.last_visit) DESC;
```